# How to get system language in ISO 639-2 format of MAC OS using cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, localization, macos

I want to retrieve the system language of a Macintosh in ISO-639-2 format (that is, in three character format).

Currently, I'm trying to use `[NSUserdefault objectforkey:@"Applelanguages"]`. This returns  the Language code in 2 character format.

Whatever API I end up using, it should support MacOS X versions from 10.3.9 forward.

Comment: Don't rush people. You'll get an answer when (1) somebody sees your question who (2) has an answer for it and (3) wants to give that answer and (4) finishes typing it. If you want answers any faster than that, hire a consultant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant sections of the document are [Internationalization Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/ChoosingLocalizations.html), [another section of the same guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/LanguageDesignations.html), and [CFLocale reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFLocaleRef/Reference/reference.html). Unfortunately I don't think there's a standard API provided which convert 639-1 to 639-2. As explained there, OS X uses a mixture of both, and the canonical form used by the OS can be obtained by `CFLocaleCreateCanonicalLanguageIdentifierFromString`. But this is not what you want, unfortunately.

I would suggest you to process the table [given here](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/English_list.php) into an NSDictionary yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For people needing this and don't want to process the table themselves, I created a [category on NSLocale](https://github.com/lickylick/NSLocale-ISO639_2) which should probably work on OS X also.